# grep recursive exclusive search

Tags: search, grep, debian

I have text I want to recursively search in `mydir/`. I would normally type `grep -r "text to find" mydir/"` but what would I type if I wanted to search all the files except a specific one?

For example, I do not want to search the file "myfile.txt" but it is contained in the directory.

What would I type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to exclude a file:

```
grep -r --exclude="myfile.txt" "text to find"
```

Answer (score 3):

One quick way is to use BASH's extended file globbing.

There is an extended negation glob that you can use as follows:

```
shopt -s extglob
grep -r "text to find" !(myfile.txt)
```

Another more flexible method is to use a combination of `find` and `xargs`. Use `find` to filter out only the files you want, and `xargs` to pass them as arguments to grep.

Something like the following sould work:

```
find -type f -not -name myfile.txt | xargs grep "text to find"
```